# Json request error instead of regular error

Tags: websocket, json.net

Trying to connect to https://www.xbtce.com via WebSocket (WebSocketSharp)
[enter link description here](https://www.xbtce.com/websocketfeedapi)

Here is the login json model

```
 {
      "Id": <some unique Id>,
      "Request": "Login",
      "Params": {
        "AuthType": "HMAC",
        "WebApiId":  <Web API Id>,
        "WebApiKey": <Web API Key>,
        "Timestamp": <timestamp (e.g. Date.now())>,
        "Signature": <signature>,
        "DeviceId":  <Device Id>
      }
    }
```

Here's my code which always gives

```
 {
  "Response": "Error",
  "Error": "Cannot parse JSON request!"
}
```

instead of normal response

```
{
  "Id": <your unique Id>,
  "Response": "Error",
  "Error": <error description from TickTrader Server>
}
```

My code

```
    private static WebSocket socket = new WebSocket("wss://cryptottlivewebapi.xbtce.net:3020");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            socket.OnMessage += Socket_OnMessage;

            socket.OnOpen += socket_Opened;
            socket.OnError += socket_Error;
            socket.Connect();



            socket.OnClose += socket_Closed;
        }

        private void Socket_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsText)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Data.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.RawData.ToString());
            }
        }



        private void socket_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }




        private void socket_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
        }

        private void socket_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string jsonSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetLogin()).ToString() ;
            MessageBox.Show(jsonSerialized);
            socket.Send(jsonSerialized);
        }

        LoginParams GetLogin()
        {
            return new LoginParams
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Request = "Login",
                Params = new Parameters
                {
                    AuthType = "HMAC",
                    WebApiId = "my id",
                    WebApiKey = "my api key",
                    Timestamp = ((Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds).ToString(),
                    Signature = Hmac.CreateToken(((Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds).ToString(), "2058e846-0a32-49b9-bc8f-4e28afd0aa9c", "my id", "my key").ToString(),

                    DeviceId = "WebBrowser"
                }
            };
        }
        public static double DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return (TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime) -
                   new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
        }
    }

public static class Hmac
    {
        public static string CreateToken(string timestamp, string id , string key, string secret)
        {
            string message = timestamp + id + key;
            secret = secret ?? "";
            var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
            byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
            using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
            {
                byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
            }
        }
    }
    public class LoginParams
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Request { get; set; }
        public Parameters Params { get; set; }
    }
    public class Parameters
    {
        public string AuthType {
            get; set; }
        public string WebApiId { get; set; }
        public string WebApiKey { get; set; }
        public string Timestamp {
            get; set; }
        public string Signature { get; set; }
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    }
```

Json serialization output

```
{
"Id": "be078b3d-2eb8-475a-97fb-89aedf775b78",
"Request": "Login",
"Params": {
    "AuthType": "HMAC",
    "WebApiId": "myid",
    "WebApiKey": "mykey",
    "Timestamp": "1467486605",
    "Signature": "NbREH0HkPadfuDESuGEHho/FwX+DFdIoCV/D5aW/gv8=",
    "DeviceId": "WebBrowser"
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is probably exactly what is reported: invalid JSON. The JSON example does not have real data so it is impossible to determine what the error is. There are JSON validators on the web and also applications, many will explain the exact error, try one.

Comment: Tried the output seems valid

Comment: The Signature is not URL safe, is that a problem for the send method?

Comment: no need to be url safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem it seems that the time stamp should not be a string but a long

```
    LoginParams GetLogin()
    {
        return new LoginParams
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Request = "Login",
            Params = new Parameters
            {
                AuthType = "HMAC",
                WebApiId = "my id",
                WebApiKey = "my api key",
                Timestamp = ((long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds).ToString(),
                Signature = Hmac.CreateToken(((long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalMilliseconds), "2058e846-0a32-49b9-bc8f-4e28afd0aa9c", "my id", "my key").ToString(),

                DeviceId = "WebBrowser"
            }
        };
    }
```